# QuickBlox downloading content receiving QBASIHTTPRequestErrorDomain code 1

Tags: ios, objective-c, quickblox

I'm using the iOS SDK to access download content from the content module. It seems in the delegate method `-(void)completedWithResult:(Result*)result`, I can have cases where `result.success` is `YES` while result.file would be nil.

```
-(void)completedWithResult:(Result*)result
{
    if (result.success) { // YES here
        if ([result isKindOfClass: [QBCFileDownloadTaskResult class]]) {
            FileDownloadTaskResult *res = (QBCFileDownloadTaskResult *)result;
            res.file; // This is NULL.
            res.errors; // This is an empty NSArray
        }
    }
}
```

Console log prints this message:

```
<QBASIHTTPRequest: 0xc26d200>
headers:(null)
body:
error:Error Domain=QBASIHTTPRequestErrorDomain Code=1 "A connection failure occurred" UserInfo=0x9f27a50 {NSUnderlyingError=0x9f18300 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Connection reset by peer", NSLocalizedDescription=A connection failure occurred}
```

Is this normal? I would expect in this case `res.success` a `NO`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try latest version of iOS SDK 1.8

http://quickblox.com/developers/IOS#Framework_changelog:

Here is one big change:

> replaced core network library ASIHTTPRequest with AFNetworking

Comment: The download link says 1.7.2; I think you meant to say 1.8 on the web page.

Comment: BTW, with all the API calls, what's the "context" used for? Is that returned in the delegate callback? Sometimes I have trouble determining exactly which returned result corresponds to which request, I wonder if I can feed the flag into it.

Comment: You can check docs http://sdk.quickblox.com/ios/
each query has an explanation which result type it will return.
Context: it's just if you need to pass some data into request - you will receive it in delegate as well -(void)completedWithResult:(Result*)result context:(id)context

Comment: Yes I've checked it, except sometimes I find myself need to differentiate different calls which return the same result class. Also the context is not documented in the calls. But yeah, I missed the delegate with context. Thanks.